# Resize image (NOT aspect ratio)

Tags: math, asp-classic

I want to resize an image, based on total image size (w*h)
I know about aspect ratio, but I'm not looking for a way to resize an image based on max_h or max_w.

**Example**
Image_H = 1000 and Image_W = 400;
that makes a total_size of 1000*400 = 400.000.

Suppose I want to limit this to max_size 100.000, which formula do I use?

(I've tried new_Image_H = Image_H*(max_size/total_size) and new_Image_W = Image_W*(max_size/total_size); this, however, results in new_Image_H = 250 and new_Image_W = 100.
The new_Total_size becomes 25.000 instead of 100.000.)

Comment: Are you trying to resize your image server side - because if you are you'll need third party component to do it in Classic ASP?

Answer (score 1):

`nW` - new image width

`nH` - new image height

`AR` - aspect ratio

`MaxS` - maximum area of square

So, let's think:

```
MaxS = nW * nH

AR = OriginalW / OriginalH = nW / nH

nW = MaxS / nH = MaxS / (nW / AR) = (MaxS * AR) / nW
nW^2 = MaxS / AR
nW = SQR (MaxS / AR) ' SQR means "square root"
```

With your values we will have:

```
nW = SQR (100000 / 0.4) = 500
nH = AR * nw = 0.4 * 500 = 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - all you need to do is work out the sizing as a percentage and then apply to width and height:

```vbs
Dim x, y, ts, alt, p, newX, newY
x = 1000
y = 400
alt = 100000
ts = x * y
p = alt / ts
newX = x * p
newY = y * p
```

Is that the kind of thing?